# How can I display the value of a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I am using the following to display a label and then the value of the field:

```
<div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageMeta.DataSourceText)</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PageMeta.DataSourceText)</div>
```

But the TextBoxFor creates a text box that I can enter data into and the field is just for information only and needs to be read only. What I need is for some Html extension that will give me the value but not in a text box. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extension methods. Just output the value to the page. If `PageMeta` can be null you should handle that also.

```
<div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageMeta.DataSourceText)</div>
<div>@Model.PageMeta.DataSourceText</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't know why I was thinking about the extension method. You were a big help to me.